# Why does this error occur when my list of obstacles gets too big?

Tags: javascript, 2d-games

I am making an infinite runner game in javascript, and the number of obstacles on the screen corresponds to the score (one obstacle for every 1000 score). When the score gets above about 30 to 35 thousand (so 30 to 35 obstacles), I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined
    at render (https://replbox.repl.it/data/web_hosting_1/GameMaster1928/Infinite-Runner-Thing/script.js:240:22)
    at loop (https://replbox.repl.it/data/web_hosting_1/GameMaster1928/Infinite-Runner-Thing/script.js:255:3)
```

My code is at https://repl.it/@GameMaster1928/Stuff.
I made the ship invincible, so you can recreate the error by just waiting.

It seems like one of my obstacles is getting undefined for some reason. Can someone please look at my code and tell me where the error is so I can fix it?

Comment: `obstacles[Math.floor(score / 1000)]` = new Obstacle(); this seems to become probelmatic mybe try `obstacles.push( new Obstacle())`

Comment: it might also help to print /debug the obstacles array every time you do a change to it (see if you add undefined somewhere)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that

Comment: I just haven't used javascript in a while.

Comment: I ran it to 50 million, and it didn't give me an error, so I think that fixed it.

Comment: I havent look at your complete code but I think you somehow skipped an entry in you array leaving one of them as undefined

Comment: Instead of putting "solved" in the question title you should write an answer and then mark it as the answer. If you say it's solved but then never supply the answer it has no value on the Stack Overflow site and is liable to get down voted or deleted.

Comment: The link has gone 404.

Comment: I fixed my problem anyway. I updated the link as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obstacles[Math.floor(score / 1000)] = new Obstacle();` This can become problematic if you don't call it for 1000 score and skip one. Use `obstacles.push( new Obstacle())` instead.